# What are good sources for free orchestra scores?

Tags: sheet-music, orchestra

Are there usable free sources for (symphonic) orchestra scores?

*I'm talking about legal sources for pieces that are now in public domain.*

Comment: Some of the works that you may think are in the public domain in the US have had their copyrights retroactively renewed.  http://chronicle.com/article/A-Professors-Fight-Over/127700/

Comment: @Tangurena Fortunately I don't have to care about USA copyright laws.

Answer (score 13):

from my bookmarks:

- http://www.sheetmusictrade.com/
- http://imslp.org/wiki/
- http://icking-music-archive.org/index.php
- http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/
- http://www.mfiles.co.uk/sheet-music.htm
- <strike>http://www.bh2000.net/score/</strike> (link dead on 7 Sept 20)
- http://www.rowy.net/sheet-music-for-piano.html
- http://www.free-scores.com/index_uk.php

plus in French:

- http://www.lespartitions.info/gratuites/index.php
- http://partitions.metronimo.com/

Comment: IMSLP.org is huge. It has a big list of other music score websites too: http://imslp.org/wiki/IMSLP:Other_music_score_websites

Answer (score 6):

Don't overlook your local library. I find that university libraries (especially when they have a music program) will have a lot more sheet music than you might think (if your library uses Library of Congress indexing, look under `M`). Many city public libraries carry orchestral and operatic scores as well (usually at the "main" or "downtown" branch).

Comment: Usually it's not legal to copy those.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: you are right, they are only for private study purpose. But it can help to decide if you want to use it with your orchestra and look harder for a free source version, invest in commercial material, etc.

Comment: You don't need to copy them.  As a kid with little money, I would borrow one or two at a time, study them for a few weeks, and swap them for others.  If I wanted them for longer, I could always renew them as no one else ever requested them.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @cardian's list:

- http://www.classical-scores.com/free/
- http://www.8notes.com/orchestra/
- http://www.freesheets.org.uk/
- http://www.dlib.indiana.edu/variations/scores/
- <strike>http://musicaviva.com/fsmd/</strike> (link no longer to music site on 7 Sept 20)

Also:

- http://www.bandmusicpdf.org/
- http://dme.mozarteum.at/DME/briefe/doclist.php

Answer (score 2):

One more: http://www.mutopiaproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @Tangurena's mention of the local library, you can check things out (pun intended) globally through inter-library loan. Try looking at https://www.worldcat.org/.